# Magento return order quantity with price

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.7

I am using the Magento API for a POS application.From Our application we can sale the Magento products.when Product is sold then immediately  Magento API calls and creates a transaction with order complete in magento 
but Problem is that

When customer purchases the products from App like 10$  and our order completes in magento with 10$  immediately and at same time customer want to return one product like 2$ from orders then how we can do that .

I have checked the credit Memo option but not cleared to me because of new in magento .
I  want to do this using the Magento code .

Can some one help me how we can back some products from orders after order completes in Magento from POS application .if any solution find then how can manage the sales,qty,inventory in Magento with order back

Thanks in advance.any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please can someone provide the solution ?